# Android Updating A TextView From A Different Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android and not 100% certain I have the terminology of my question correct, but here it is.

I have a layout that has a `TextView` that I want to reflect a setting. The problem I am facing is that the Setting page ("customsignalsetup") is navigated to from the page that the `TextView` I want to update is situated on. When the option is changed on the settings page, and closed using `Finish()`, the `TextView` hasn't updated. However, if I close the page the `TextView` is on, then open it again, it has updated.

Here's my code:

**TextView Update Code (Before any changes on the settings page)**

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("CustomSignalSettings", 0);
        TextView CustLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cunitslabel);
        CustLabel.setText("Custom (" + settings.getString("CustomSignalUnit", "").toString() + ") =");
```

**Code To Handle "Settings" Pressed From Menu And Switch To Settings Page**

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.custom_signal_setup:
       // Open Settings Page
                Intent intent = new Intent(PLCActivity.this, customsignalsetup.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            case R.id.help:
               //get help
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**Setting Page Code To Update TextView**

```
    public class customsignalsetup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customplcsettingspopup);

     Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     public void onClick(View v) {
           switch(v.getId()){
               case R.id.save:

//THE BELOW LINE IS SUPPOSED TO SET 'CustLabel' TO THE TEXTVIEW TO BE UPDATED
                   TextView CustLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cunitslabel);

                   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("CustomSignalSettings", 0);
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                   editor.putString("CustomSignalUnit",CusUnit.getText().toString());
                   editor.commit();

// THE BELOW LINE IS SUPPOSED TO UPDATE THE TEXTVIEW ON A DIFFERENT PAGE                  
 CustLabel.setText("Custom (" + settings.getString("CustomSignalUnit", "").toString() + ") =");

                   finish();
           }
        }


    }
```

My code throws no errors, but the TextView simply doesn't update. Im assuming this is because the activity loaded the original textview hasn't ended yet and only future labels will be updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this line like this so you will get the updated value everytime.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
   CustLabel.setText("Custom (" + settings.getString("CustomSignalUnit", "").toString() + ") =");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very simple too!